# Filter videos by there content in youtube API V3

Tags: video, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to make a youtube search in `Islamic` country so I need to filter out those videos which is `anti-Islam` like Porn, sexy, songs etc. 
Currently I'm using youtube data api v3 for searching videos, but I want when ever user search it filter the search according to specific content, remove those videos which is `anti-Islamic`.
Is there any way to do that.
Thanks....

Comment: Did you got any solution  for this  , I want to. achieve  something  like this.  Actually  I want to create  a video islami app,  where  every  video  should  be related  t0 Islam.  Imagine a Islamic. YouTube.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer - I work at the company that developed this API

You should check out NetSpark's [Nude Detect API](http://www.nudedetect.com), which delivers a highly accurate confidence rating for images with nudity or minimal dress. For a religiously conservative market that would not tolerate accidental exposure you would probably want to limit content to what is rated up to a 1% confidence rating.

It is available here on Mashape to test out for free or subscribe to a usage plan- https://market.mashape.com/netspark/nude-detect

There is the capability for this to be adapted to perform the inspection on video instead of still images, and you can contact the developers for a custom quote.